# How to show the selected value from the drop down list and show it in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want it to show the selected value from the drop down list and show it on gridview. It is supposed to query from the  database using Where to indicate the selected value to show. For example, I select james from the drop down list. It supposes to go to the database and query james row. After that the grid view is supposed to show only one value which james. But now I am having a problem where the grid view show every data that is available in the database.

```
public partial class Search_Engine : System.Web.UI.Page
{
#region Database

static string HostName = "localhost";
static string DatabaseName = "finalproject";
static string TableName = "truckinfo";
//static string TableBucket = "bucketbrigade";
static string UserName = "root";
static string Password = "";

//--- Used for access to database infomation-----
string ConnStr = "Data Source=" + HostName + ";" +
                 "Database=" + DatabaseName + ";" +
                 "User ID=" + UserName + ";" +
                 "Password=" + Password;

string Qry = "";

MySqlConnection Con;
MySqlCommand Cmd;
MySqlDataReader Rdr;

#endregion
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        BindData();


        using (Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            Con.Open();
            using (Cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM truckinfo", Con))
            {

                using (Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (Rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = Rdr;
                        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "truckplateno";
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
        Con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " +
                          DatabaseName + "." + TableName , Con);


        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        Con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}



protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{




}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
    Con.Open();
    try
    {
        String getquery;
        // String a;
        getquery = DropDownList1.Text;
        TextBox1.Text = getquery;
        // a = TextBox2.Text;
        //  TextBox1.Text = a;
        Qry = @"SELECT * FROM finalproject.truckinfo WHERE truckplateno=" + "'" + getquery + "'" + ";";
        Cmd = new MySqlCommand(Qry, Con);
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
        BindData();
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you call `BindData` at the end of `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` you are effectively rebuilding that entire table. Maybe pass the query as a parameter in `BindData`. However, I hope that this is just a "learning" project, because the way you build these queries, you expose yourself to massive security vulnerabilities (google sql injection attacks).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `selected value` using `SelectedValue` of dropdownlist and then query `database` using this value.

```
getquery = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Also you are using `BindData` method which will always `select all` data from `database` you need to `seprate` this method so only `selected data` is bind to gridview.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String getquery;
getquery = DropDownList1.Text;
MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
Con.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM finalproject.truckinfo WHERE truckplateno='" + getquery + "'", Con);
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

Con.Close();

}
```

You are calling `ExecuteNonQuey` function which is used to `Insert` or `Update` data in `database` so it will not `return` any data.

> Also when using `SqlDataAdapter` you don't need to explicitly call
>   `Open` and `Close` function for opening and closing connection.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DropDownlist_SelectedIndexChanged function to the following:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    Con.Open();
    string getquery = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    TextBox1.Text = getquery;
    // a = TextBox2.Text;
    //  TextBox1.Text = a;
    Qry = @"SELECT * FROM finalproject.truckinfo WHERE truckplateno=" + "'" + getquery + "'" + ";";
    MySqlCommand ddlCMD = new MySqlCommand(Qry, Con);
    MySqlDataAdapter msda = new MySqlDataAdapter(ddlCMD);
    msda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
    catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
finally{
    Con.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: What should I put in the finally braces

Comment: @user14963 remove Con.Close() from try-block to finally-block. I changed the answer